# Spark as Data Ingestion/Onboarding to HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-nifi, hadoop-plugins, gobblin

While exploring various tools like [Nifi, Gobblin etc.], I have observed that Databricks is now promoting for using Spark for data ingestion/on-boarding.

We have a spark[scala] based application running on YARN. So far we are working on a hadoop and spark cluster where we manually place required data files in HDFS first and then run our spark jobs later. 
Now when we are planning to make our application available for the client we are expecting any type and number of files [mainly csv, jason, xml etc.] from any data source [ftp, sftp, any relational and nosql database] of huge size [ranging from GB to PB].

Keeping this in mind we are looking for options which could be used for data on-boarding and data sanity before pushing data into HDFS.

Options which we are looking for based on priority:
1) Spark for data ingestion and sanity: As our application is written and is running on spark cluster, we are planning to use the same for data ingestion and sanity task as well. 
We are bit worried about Spark's support for many datasources/file types/etc. Also, we are not sure if we try to copy data from let's say any FTP/SFTP then will all workers will write data on HDFS in parallel? Is there any limitation while using it? Is there any Audit trail maintained by Spark while this data copy?

2) Nifi in clustered mode: How good Nifi would be for this purpose? Can it be used for any datasource and for any size of file? Will be maintain the Audit trail? Would Nifi we able to handle such large files? How large cluster would be required in case we try to copy GB - PB of data and perform certain sanity on top of that data before pushing it to HDFS?

3) Gobblin in clustered mode: Would like to hear similar answers as that for Nifi?

4) If at all there is any other good option available for this purpose with lesser infra/cost involved and better performance?

Any guidance/pointers/comparisions for above mentioned tools and technologies would be appreciated.

Best Regards,
Bhupesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing certain R&D and considering the fact that using NIFI or goblin will demand for more infrastructure cost. I have started testing Spark for data on-boarding.

SO far I have tried using Spark job for importing data [present at a remote staging area/node] into my HDFS and I am able to do that by mounting that remote location with all my spark cluster worker nodes. Doing this made that location local to those workers, hence spark job ran properly and data is on-boarded to my HDFS.

Since my whole project is going to be on Spark, hence keeping data on-boarding part on spark would not cost anything extra to me. So far I am going good. Hence I would suggest to others as well, if you already have spark cluster and hadoop cluster up and running then instead of adding extra cost [where cost could be a major constraint] go for spark job for data on-boarding.